# Django. How to migrate just a particular app in mongo

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I want to migrate the models logging app into the thor (mongodb) database. But when I say " python manage.py migrate --database=thor ", it migrates other apps as well. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone help?

```
class AuthRouter(object):
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth application.
"""
route_app_labels = {'models_logging'}

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'models_logging':
        return 'thor'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'models_logging':
        return 'thor'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
    """
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'models_logging' or \
       obj2._meta.app_label == 'models_logging':
       return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
    database.
    """
    if app_label == 'models_logging':
        return db == 'thor'
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python manage.py migrate <app_label> --database=<db_name>
```

You can read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#migrate)